# Moving Invited Trello Member from Notifications to His Boards

Tags: trello, notifications

I invited someone to join my organization and a shared board on Trello. He can access these through notifications but they aren't showing up on his dashboard of boards.

Comment: Please clarify what application you are talking about so that we can offer you the correct help.

Comment: Sorry. The application is Trello.

Answer (score 1):

He may have to log out and back in, or accept the invitation to join the boards before they show up in his list.